# replication using multiple kafka brokers and node-rdkafka admin createTopic gives Time out

Tags: node.js, docker, apache-kafka

I am trying to setup an envrironment to learn about replication in kafka. However, executing below code gives timed out error. I could not find out what the problem is.

If I were to use single broker instance with docker containers and no replication it would work fine.

```bash
    error creating topic:  LibrdKafkaError: Local: Timed out
        at Function.createLibrdkafkaError [as create] (/Users/my-name/Developer/test/kafka-nodejs/kafka-local-docker/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/error.js:456:10)
        at /Users/my-name/Developer/test/kafka-nodejs/kafka-local-docker/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/admin.js:132:28 {
      code: -185,
      errno: -185,
      origin: 'kafka'
    }
```

```js
    const Kafka = require('node-rdkafka');
    
    const admin = Kafka.AdminClient.create({
        'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9091,localhost:9092,localhost:9093',
        'broker.version.fallback': '0.10.2.1',
        'log.connection.close' : false
    });
    
    const topicName = 'cool-topic-4';
    
    const newTopic = {
        topic: topicName,
        num_partitions: 2,
        replication_factor: 3,
        config: {
            'min.insync.replicas': '2',
        }
    }
    
    // create a new kafka topic 
    admin.createTopic(newTopic, (err) => {
            if (err)
                console.log("error creating topic: ", err);
            else
                console.log("topic created: ", topicName);
        }
    );
```

```yaml
---
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    container_name: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9091:9091"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_NODE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9091,PLAINTEXT_NODE://kafka1:29091

  
  kafka2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    container_name: kafka2
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_NODE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_NODE://kafka2:29092

  
  kafka3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    container_name: kafka3
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_NODE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093,PLAINTEXT_NODE://kafka3:29093
```

Not sure if this is helpful but here is a part of `docker container logs`:

```bash
kafka2     |    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
kafka2     | [2023-07-28 15:56:38,308] INFO [Controller id=2, targetBrokerId=1] Client requested connection close from node 1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka2     | [2023-07-28 15:56:38,410] INFO [Controller id=2, targetBrokerId=1] Node 1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka2     | [2023-07-28 15:56:38,410] WARN [Controller id=2, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9091) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka2     | [2023-07-28 15:56:38,410] INFO [Controller id=2, targetBrokerId=3] Node 3 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka2     | [2023-07-28 15:56:38,410] WARN [Controller id=2, targetBrokerId=3] Connection to node 3 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka2     | [2023-07-28 15:56:38,410] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=2] Controller 2's connection to broker localhost:9093 (id: 3 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
kafka2     | java.io.IOException: Connection to localhost:9093 (id: 3 rack: null) failed.
kafka2     |    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:70)
kafka2     |    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:292)
kafka2     |    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:246)
kafka2     |    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
kafka2     | [2023-07-28 15:56:38,410] INFO [Controller id=2, targetBrokerId=3] Client requested connection close from node 3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka2     | [2023-07-28 15:56:38,410] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=2] Controller 2's connection to broker localhost:9091 (id: 1 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
kafka2     | java.io.IOException: Connection to localhost:9091 (id: 1 rack: null) failed.
kafka2     |    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:70)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the inter broker protocol correctly. By default, it's PLAINTEXT, but you've set up the advertised listeners as localhost rather than the container service names, therefore each broker will try to connect to themselves on the incorrect ports

Comment: I also provide container service names `PLAINTEXT://localhost:9091,PLAINTEXT_NODE://kafka1:29091` for each container.

Comment: Like I said, the inter broker protocol is not using `PLAINTEXT_NODE`  listener unless you explicitly configure it. it'll only use `PLAINTEXT`... Look https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/zk-single-kafka-multiple.yml#L26

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. This solved my problem. Documentation on the topic in addition to useful compose file example would be much appreciated if you can. Thanks again :)

Comment: The documentation is on Kafka website and that link is a compose example